# Bash/AWK/SED Match and ReWrite a string of numbers (date) in a line

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have a text file with the following contents repeating about 60 times coming from a converted .ics file:

```
Start Vak
Tijd van: 20120411T093000Z
Tijd tot: 20120411T100000Z
Klas(sen) en Docent(en): VPOS0A1 VPOS0A2 Mariel Kers
Vak: Ex. Verst. beperk.
Lokaal: 7.05
Einde Vak
```

I want to rewrite the "Tijd van" and "Tijd tot" values to become a good date (in a bash script on a gnu/linux system with awk,sed and grep etc.). I tried to use awk to find it:

```sh
awk '/^Tijd.*[:digit:][:digit:]Z$/; { getline; print $0; }' rooster2.txt
```

and grep:

```sh
egrep '/^Tijd(.*)[:digit:][:digit:]Z$/' rooster2.txt
```

But they both do not even find the line.

What I want is to get that date rewritten to a more bash parsable/feasible time format like the EPOCH or something like 31.04.2012 13:00:00. I do not want to replace or rewrite the whole line, just the specific string! Anything, either tips, examples or links are welcome and very usefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(Tijd ...: )(....)(..)(..).(..)(..)(..)./\1 \4.\3.\2 \5:\6:\7/' FILE
```

Comment: I would suggest `\2-\3-\4` (e.g. 2012-04-11) to write the date. It's unambiguous and it sorts the same lexically and chronologically.

Comment: Thank you! Did not knew SED did that ass well.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your `awk` code:

1. While `[:digit:]` refers to *"any digit"*, you still need another pair of square brackets (`[...]`) for the character group: `[[:digit:]]` (Just image you wanted "*a,any digit or _*" , this would be `[a[:digit:]_]`, the outer square brackets defining the character group.)
2. The semicolon (`;`) between your *pattern* (`/.../`) and the corresponding *action* (`{...}`) separates the two, so you have a *pattern* with no action, resulting in the standard *action* `{print $0}`, and a second *action* without a *pattern*, resulting in it being performed for all *records* (i.e. lines).
3. The `getline` asks `awk` to read the next *record* (i.e. line) before continuing.

Taking all that together your code does the following:

- Print all lines matching `/^Tijd.*[:digit:][:digit:]Z$/` (that is none, since `[:digit:]` translates to *"one of :,d,i,g, or t"*).
- Additionally, for all lines: read the *next* line and print it.

Thus, it will print all but the first line (because that is the only one that is not the *next* one to any other line).

Assuming you just want to print the lines matching *"starting with 'Tijd' and ending with two digits followed by a 'Z'"* you could use the following code:

```sh
awk '/^Tijd.*[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]Z$/{ print $0; }' rooster2.txt
```

Since `{print $0}` is the standard *action* you could even shorten that to

```sh
awk '/^Tijd.*[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]Z$/' rooster2.txt
```

To solve your actual problem you could use something like the following:

```sh
awk '/^Tijd.*[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]Z$/{year=substr($NF,1,4);month=substr($NF,5,2);day=substr($NF,7,2);hour=substr($NF,10,2);min=substr($NF,12,2);sec=substr($NF,14,2);$NF=day"."month"."year" "hour":"min":"sec}1' rooster2.txt
```

This works as follows:

- For *records* (i.e lines) matching the *pattern* (`/.../`), rearrange the *last field* (`$NF`) to your needs.
- Print all *records* (i.e. lines) (`1` is a *pattern* matching all *records* (i.e. lines) with no specified *action*, resulting in the standard one (`{print $0}`))

Note that GNU `awk` also has a `strftime` function.
However, that needs the timestamp to be in a different format.
If you want to use that you must still rearrange the *field*, first:

```sh
awk -v FORMAT="%c" '/^Tijd.*[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]Z$/{$NF=strftime(FORMAT,mktime(substr($NF,1,4)" "substr($NF,5,2)" "substr($NF,7,2)" "substr($NF,10,2)" "substr($NF,12,2)" "substr($NF,14,2)))}1' rooster2.txt
```

Now, you just need to adjust `FORMAT` to your needs to change the format.
See `man strftime` for details.

Answer (score 0):

As a ruby one-liner; requiring `time` for `Time.parse` then replacing
matching regexp. You may look [strftime](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.3/Time#strftime-instance_method) method for formatting time
output.

```
[slmn@uriel ~]$ ruby -rtime -ne 'puts $_.sub(/(Tijd (van|tot): )(.*)/) { $1 + Time.parse($3).strftime("%D %T") }' < yourfile.txt
Start Vak
Tijd van: 04/11/12 09:30:00
Tijd tot: 04/11/12 10:00:00
Klas(sen) en Docent(en): VPOS0A1 VPOS0A2 Mariel Kers
Vak: Ex. Verst. beperk.
Lokaal: 7.05
Einde Vak
```

Comment: Thanks! Have tried it but I find the sed one posted above fit more in my bash themed script.

Comment: In the end I went with this ruby one-liner. Gave me more sorting options. Thanks!